# Dynamic Change translation of Qt App

Tags: c++, qt

In my app, i have several QDialog forms. 
when i install and change translation of my app. MainWindow has been affected but all other dialogs didn't change to new Language.so, 
how can i change all forms lang at runtime(dynamic)?
Please help me

```
    void MainWindow::SetUILang()
    {
        QTranslator qtTranslator;
        qtTranslator.load(QString("tr_fa"), "./Lang");
        qApp->installTranslator(&qtTranslator);
        ui->retranslateUi(this);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamically change the language on your application, a `changeEvent` of type `QEvent::LanguageChange` is emitted. You'll have to catch that and reset your texts everywhere (using the `tr` function)>

```
void myclass::changeEvent(QEvent *event) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange) {
        // Set all texts
    }
    else {
        QWidget::changeEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: In Main Window. when user click on information button. a new instance of information form create and show it, i've been add changeEvent code but nor work.

Comment: If you create a new instance after you changed the language, all texts should be translated correctly. Did you enclose them with the `tr` function?

Comment: :Yes, It's in UI Designer form and i 've been checked translatable

Comment: Did you provide any translations? Sorry for asking such stupid questions, but sometimes it's the simple things...

Comment: No, it's there. MainWindow translate successfully but other forms don't :D

Comment: Hmm, that's very strange. I haven't used the UI designer too much, so I don't how translation works with forms created there, sorry.